# MSMQ in c# with Sender and Receiver classes

Tags: c#, msmq

Alright, I'm again struggling with some piece of code, and it doesn't work.
Basically, I have a simple Student class with name, surname, and group number:

```
[XmlRoot]
    public class Student
    {
        string name;
        string surname;
        int group;

        public Student(string _name, string _surname, int _group)
        {
            name= _name;
            surname= _surname;
            group= _group;
        }

        public Student()
        {
        }

        public void writeAttributes()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}",name, surname, group);
        }
    }
```

Then, my solution in Visual Studio, has two projects: one, the sender, the other the receiver.
What I'm trying to accomplish is to send an instance of this class through MSMQ(asynchronously).
Here's the sender code:

```
class Program
    {
        static MessageQueue mq;

        static void SendMessage(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Messaging.Message msg = new System.Messaging.Message();

            try
            {
                msg.Label = "Message Label";

                mq.Send(new Student("Name", "Surname", 1000));
                Console.WriteLine("We send a Student");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Timer timer1 = new Timer();           

            if (MessageQueue.Exists(@".\private$\NewPrivateQ"))
                mq = new MessageQueue(@".\private$\NewPrivateQ");
            else
                mq = MessageQueue.Create(@".\private$\NewPrivateQ");    

            mq.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(Student) });

            //init the timer
            System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            myTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(SendMessage);
            myTimer.Interval = 3000;
            myTimer.Enabled = true;

            while (true) ;
        }
    }
```

I use a timer, to send the information every 3 seconds.
And, here's the receiver code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void OnMessageArrival(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            MessageQueue mq = (MessageQueue)ar.AsyncState;

            try
            {
                Message msg = mq.EndReceive(ar);

                var message = (Student)msg.Body;
                //Console.WriteLine(message);
                message.writeAttributes();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);                
            }
            finally
            {
                mq.BeginReceive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), mq,
                new AsyncCallback(OnMessageArrival));
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MessageQueue mq = new MessageQueue(@".\private$\NewPrivateQ");

            mq.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(Student) });

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    IAsyncResult iar = mq.BeginReceive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), mq, new AsyncCallback(OnMessageArrival));                   
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't receive anything. I've tried a multitude of ways. I've tried to change the XmlFormatter to BinaryFormatter, with no success.

Another helpful information: the Student class it's included in both projects: the sender, and the receiver.

Answer (score 1):

XmlSerializer doesn't support serializing private fields so for this to work you would need to use `public` properties.

If you need that level of serialization control you should have a look at [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx).

Comment: After changing from private to public fields, I get the same "Timeout for the requested operation has expired", a sign that those 5 seconds from the receiver have passed.

Comment: Yeah so that's a different problem from the serialization not actually working, that's like the communication between your pub/sub isn't working correctly.